# Generate txt report of files copied between two folders

Tags: windows, powershell-5.0

I have a script that copies audio files from one folder to another.

Script:

```
$tot = 0
$files = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\List.txt'
$location = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance\'
$destination = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance Copy\'

Get-Content $files | % {
 
    $result = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$location*$_*"

    If($result) {
       gci -recurse "$location*$_*" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance Copy\List source file locations.txt" -append
       $musicName = $result.Name        
       $tot+=1       
       Write-Host "$musicName copied"
       Copy-Item $result.FullName -Destination $destination\$($_.Name)              
    }
}

Write-Host " $tot Files were copied! " -ForegroundColor Green

choice /c e /n /m 'Process finished.[E]xit'
        switch ($LASTEXITCODE) {
          1 { ' ' }
        }
        
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq "1") {
            break
        }

exit
```

The result in the txt file is like this:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                         
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                         
-a----        03/12/2021     14:45        6948260 Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real (Dj 'S' Bootleg Extended Dance Re Mix).mp3                                      

    Directory: C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                         
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                         
-a----        03/12/2021     14:45        7548241 Electric Light Orchestra - Last Train To London (Bootleg Extended Dance Remix).mp3
```

But I want to get results grouped Directory like:

```
Directory: C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        03/12/2021     14:45        6948260 Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real (Dj 'S' Bootleg Extended Dance Re Mix).mp3
-a----        03/12/2021     14:45        7548241 Electric Light Orchestra - Last Train To London (Bootleg Extended Dance Remix).mp3
```

How to generate in a txt file the information of the copied files and grouped by Directory, so that you can know from which folders the files were copied?

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style OK, I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That worked:

```
Get-Content $files | % {

  $result = gci -recurse "$location*\*$_*" -Include *.mp3

  If($result) { 
    Add-Content $destination"List source file locations.txt" -Value $result.Fullname
    $musicName = $result.Name    
    $tot+=1       
    Write-Host "$musicName copied"
    Copy-Item $result.FullName -Destination $destination\$($_.Name)
  } 
} 

$List= Get-Content $destination"List source file locations.txt"
       Remove-Item -Path $destination"List source file locations.txt"
       gci -recurse $List | Out-File -filepath $destination"List source file locations.txt"
```

The Add-content command adds the selected records to the txt file.

The Get-content command generated the $list variable which was read by the gci command which grouped the txt file by Directory.

If in your report the same folder appears twice eg.

```
\musics\soft
  a.mp3
  b.mp3

\musics\hard
  c.mp3
  d.mp3

\musics\soft
  e.mp3
  f.mp3
```

insert in the line:
$List= Get-Content $destination"List source file locations.txt" `| sort | get-unique`

we will have:

```
\musics\soft
  a.mp3
  b.mp3
  e.mp3
  f.mp3

\musics\hard
  c.mp3
  d.mp3
```